# How to copy a range of Excel values in one worksheet with a defined row number and paste special (paste values and transpose)

Tags: excel, vba

first time using vba and I have run into a problem.

The way my Excel is set up is in a sheet called "Key Values" there are a list of cells with formulas spanning from columns J to DY. This data is over rows 7 to 34. I am trying to copy each row and paste special (as values and transposing them) into a singular column in a different sheet called "Shares"

Originally I wrote the vba code out manually and it worked fine, however I wanted to clean up the code as I imagine the manual version can be made into a loop. This is where I ran into the problem.

Original Code: *(note obviously this isn't the whole thing, just part of it to give an idea of what it looked like)*

```
    Sheets("Key Values").Range("J7:DY7").Copy
    Sheets("Shares").Range("I4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True

    Sheets("Key Values").Range("J8:DY8").Copy
    Sheets("Shares").Range("I124").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True

    Sheets("Key Values").Range("J9:DY9").Copy
    Sheets("Shares").Range("I244").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
```

I tried to make the above into a loop to go from rows 7 to 34 but keep running into an error.

Code with Loop (and problem):

```
Sub MacroTestv2()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
        
' i is the number of rows in the Key Values
' j is the row corresponding to the Key Values that will be copied
' k is the row number where the Key Values will be pasted (as values and transposed)

    i = 34
    k = 4
    
    For j = 7 To i
    
    Sheets("Key Values").Range(Cells(j, 10), Cells(j, 129)).Copy
    Sheets("Shares").Range("I", k).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    
    k = k + 120
    
    Next

    Sheets("Shares").Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `Range("I", k)` should be `Range("I" & k)` or `Cells(k,"I")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integer values are limited to 32,767 so use Long. Avoid unqualified refences like `Cells(j, 10)` because they default to the active sheet.

```vb
Sub MacroTestv2()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
        
' i is the number of rows in the Key Values
' j is the row corresponding to the Key Values that will be copied
' k is the row number where the Key Values will be pasted (as values and transposed)

    i = 34
    k = 4
      
    Const NUM = 120
    For j = 7 To i
    
        Sheets("Key Values").Range("J" & j).Resize(, NUM).Copy 'J:DY
        Sheets("Shares").Range("I" & k).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
              Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
        
        k = k + NUM
    
    Next
    Sheets("Shares").Activate
    Sheets("Shares").Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```